# Is it better to pass back String or Object in the ResponseEntity<>?

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson, spring-rest

I have a controller that returns ResponseEntity. Now I have altered this code and added a bunch of filters using ObjectMapper. After this change I am returning a String as the response.

Sample code below:

```
public ResponseEntity<String> search() {
SearchResult searchResults = service.search(criteria);
objectMapper.setFilterProvider(new SimpleFilterProvider()
                .addFilter("firstFilter", new FirstFilter())
                .addFilter("secondFilter",new SecondFilter()));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(searchResults), OK);
}
```

Now my question is, is this a good way of doing it. Does it have any implications. What is the difference between sending the actual Object back as opposed to the String variant of it. Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: With `ResponseEntity` objects, you can have some fine-tuned control of cache-headers such as `Cache-control`, `Pragma` etc.,

Comment: Oh okay, assuming that I don't require any of these additional features, are there any other implications on using it like this?

Comment: So, I don't have exhaustive list. But, `ResponseEntity` is mostly used with `RestController` and `RestTemplate`. If you want to return a view, then returning string is okay. I don't know what all you are going to do with  response. It heavily depends on that usage.

Answer (score 1):

[`ResponseEntity<T>`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html) represents the entire HTTP response. Besides the entity itself, its API allows you to set headers and a status code to the response.

Returning a plain `String` won't give you much flexibility in the long run. If you need to add a header to the response, for example, you need to change the method return type.