# Restful Webservice string response

Tags: java, rest, web-services

I have an endpoint where it supposes to sends a string as a response. My question is do I need to use to response Entity to send string response or just return the string to the consumer?

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/word")
public String getWord() {
    String response = "webservice";
    return response;
}
```

**Second approach:**

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/word", produces ={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
public ResponseEntity<String> getWord() {
    String response = "webservice";
    return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

What is the correct approach to send just a string or use response entity?

Comment: Possible Dupliate: See the answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44497859/is-it-better-to-pass-back-string-or-object-in-the-responseentity  It contains the reasons why ResponseEntity is preferable - in short, it gives you more flexibility going forward.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the correct approach to send just a string or use response entity?

The Spring MVC [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-return-types) lists a number of types that can be returned from controller methods.

As I previously answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44499444/1426227) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49673748/1426227), [`ResponseEntity<T>`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html) represents the **entire HTTP response**. Besides the *body*, its API allows you to set *headers* and a *status code* to the response.

Returning just a bean instance or a string is fine but doesn't give you much flexibility: In the future, if you need to add a header to the response or modify the status code, for example, you need to change the method return type.